# Vba causing Excel 2003 to crash

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, crash

So after a great deal of time and effort I am no closer to solving this issue. 
Excel crashes running any vba code ("stopped working and needs to close"), either as a sub routine or a function.
Literally I'm on a fresh install tried uninstalling reinstalling, option explicit, running on the lowest non-recommended security settings and the thing still crashes.
When I say simple code I mean crazy simple code see below

```
Public function crazy(input1 as string)as string
crazy =input1 & "slowly going mad"
End function
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? Inbuilt functions work fine

This is a Windows 7 OS running office 2003 if it helps

Comment: How are you calling that function, and what are you doing with the resulting string?  Can you run something like `Public Sub blah()
    Range("A1").Value = "Crazy?"
End Sub` from the VBA editor, and have it put the string in cell A1?

Comment: No I have tried multiple different variations using different code. Even recording a simple macro just selecting various cells causes excel to crash. I was thinking that it might be to do with permissions on the hard drive but I installed on another drive and it still didn't work... Perhaps there is an issue with the OS, permissions, antivirus... Next try will be a full reinstall. I've also installed latest service pack with no luck there either.

Comment: Just used virtual box to install on Xp and everything works fine... therefore it has to be something to do with how the OS is set up. Virtual box won't allow 64 bit win 7 installation so need to try and understand why this is happening.

Comment: Perhaps your windows scripting services are corrupt..? Do wscript and/or cscript work to run basic console VBS scripts?  Have you run a `sfc /scannow` to check for corrupt system files?

Comment: Not sure on how to check if the scripting services are corrupt.. Have run sfc /SCANNOW but it didn't find any integrity violations? Sorry not v. Savvy in this area (CMD). Thanks for any continued support...how might I check wscript or cscript?

Comment: Make a simple VBS script and then run `cscript scriptname.vbs` and see if it works. :)

Comment: Yes this seems to work fine. I had to traverse the directories to the file location. Not sure if this should be necessary ...again sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling OS everything is working as expected. It would have been nice to find out what the issue was without having to take this kind of drastic action. I probably messed something up along the way. Perhaps an environment variable? Anyhow thanks for the input.